# Select all PNG images

Tags: html, css, image

How can apply a css style just to **PNG** images?

```
.pngImages {opacity:0.75}
.pngImages:hover {opacity:1}
```

I have many pages that contain repeated **PNG** files.
How can apply this class to all of them without specify img `class="pngImage"` ...

A thing like this but just for png images:

```
div {background-color:#ddd}
```

Comment: All your images are png or some are gif, jpg, etc.?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to add a class attribute?

Comment: Good creative question +1. But I dont think there is a specific CSS Solution to it. - @user2586454

Answer (score 9):

You can use the attribute selector

```
img[src$=".png"]
```

This selects all png images

Comment: Only possible issue would be something like `<img src="image.png?attr=val">` if you have some routing to dynamic output or are using query string for cache-busting, or if you have mixed case like `PNG` or `Png` (there are probably more plausible exceptions). It's more correct to say it selects all images whose `src` ends with exactly `.png`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you only need to take care of `<img>` tags, and not background-images as well:

```
img[src$='.png'] {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

This selects all image tags which have an src attribute value ending in `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[attribute$='value']` selector to do that:

```
img[src$=".png"] { opacity:0.75; }
img[src$=".png"]:hover { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to do this using an attribute selector [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) for example:

`img[src$=".png"]{border:2px solid #8c0000;}`

You might need to test this in Internet Explorer to make sure that it is picked up.